# How do I make returns back to the main method?

Tags: java

I need help in finding out how to get the Fvalue1 from method1 and return it to the main method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FutureValues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("present value  : ");
        double Pvalue = CONSOLE.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("interest rate  : ");
        double Interest = CONSOLE.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("number of years : ");
        double Years = CONSOLE.nextDouble();

        method1(Pvalue, Interest, Years);

        System.out.print("The future value using compound interest = " + Fvalue1);

        return Fvalue1;
    }

    public static double method1(double Pvalue, double Interest, double Years) {
        return Fvalue1 = Pvalue * Math.pow(1 + Interest / 100, Years);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the answer incorrectly, and not setting it in the calling function. This should work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FutureValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("present value   : ");
        double Pvalue = CONSOLE.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("interest rate   : ");
        double Interest = CONSOLE.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("number of years : ");
        double Years = CONSOLE.nextDouble();

        double Fvalue1 = method1(Pvalue, Interest, Years);

        System.out.print("The future value using compound interest = " + Fvalue1);
    }

    public static double method1(double Pvalue, double Interest, double Years) {
        return Pvalue * Math.pow(1 + Interest / 100, Years);
    }
}
```

Key changes being:

```
double Fvalue1 = method1(Pvalue, Interest, Years);
```

and

```
return Pvalue * Math.pow(1 + Interest / 100, Years);
```

Comment: oh wait when I put in what you put it says "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]."

Comment: Revert the "public static void main(String[] args) {" line. I updated the post. Sorry about that

Comment: ok the line that says return Fvalue1; the output shows an error stating "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"

Comment: remove `return Fvalue1;` from main method.